# How to make these two methods one?

Tags: java, java-17

I have two methods that are very similar. So I want to reduce this to one method, but I don't know how to do it.

Used like this:

```
mapClassBToClassA("a list o ClassB objs", "a list of ClassA objs");
mapClassCToClassA("a list o ClassC objs", "a list of ClassA objs");
```

I want to change to:

```
mapClassToClassA("a list o ClassB objs", "a list of ClassA objs");
mapClassToClassA("a list o ClassC objs", "a list of ClassA objs");
```

Method ONE B => A

```
public void mapClassBToClassA(List<ClassB> b, List<ClassA> a){
   Comparator<ClassB> sortFunc = Comparator.comparing(ClassB::getDate);
   Collections.sort(b, sortFunc);
   for (ClassA aObj : a){
      LocalDate dateA = aObj.getDate();
      ClassB bObjToUse = null;
      for (ClassB bObj : b){
         LocalDate dateB = bObj.getDate();
         if (dateB.isAfter(dateA)){
            break;
         }
         else {
            bObjToUse = bObj; 
         } 
      }
      if (bObjToUse != null){
         aObj.setClassB(bObjToUse);
      }
   }
}
```

Method TWO C => A

```
public void mapClassCToClassA(List<ClassC> c, List<ClassA> a){
   Comparator<ClassC> sortFunc = Comparator.comparing(ClassC::getDate);
   Collections.sort(c, sortFunc);
   for (ClassA aObj : a){
      LocalDate dateA = aObj.getDate();
      ClassC cObjToUse = null;
      for (ClassC cObj : c){
         LocalDate dateC = cObj.getDate();
         if (dateC.isAfter(dateA)){
            break;
         }
         else {
            cObjToUse = cObj; 
         } 
      }
      if (cObjToUse != null){
         aObj.setClassC(cObjToUse);
      }
   }
}
```

I want to make some thing like:

```
public void mapClassToClassA(List< **xx** > t, List<ClassA> a){
   Comparator< **xx** > sortFunc = Comparator.comparing( **xx** ::getDate);
   Collections.sort( t , sortFunc);
   for (ClassA aObj : a){
      LocalDate dateA = aObj.getDate();
      **xx** objToUse = null;
      for (**xx** obj : t){
         LocalDate dateT = obj.getDate();
         if (dateT.isAfter(dateA)){
            break;
         }
         else {
            objToUse = bObj; 
         } 
      }
      if (objToUse != null){
         aObj.setClassXXX(objToUse);
      }
   }
}
```

I tried using generics

```
public <T> void mapToArende(List<T> t, List<ClassA> a){
        ...
           T objToUse = null;
```

but that way:

- I can't do the comparator, since this does not work

  ```
  Comparator.comparing(T::getFromdat);
  ```
- And not the call to obj.getDate(), here I found a solution using reflection, but people recommend not to do that. But it works. How should I do instead?

  ```
  Method m = obj.getClass().getMethod("getDate");
  LocalDate dateT = (LocalDate) m.invoke(obj);
  ```
- I can't figure out how to make the call to aObj.setClassXXX() as the method name is different for classB & classC

I read about lambdas but have some trouble seeing how to do with those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't add a common interface to these classes you can add some functions to the method parameters:

```java
public <T> void mapClassToClassA(List<T> t, List<ClassA> a,
                                 Function<T, LocalDate> dateGetter,
                                 BiConsumer<ClassA, T> setter) {

    Comparator<T> sortFunc = Comparator.comparing(dateGetter);
    Collections.sort(t, sortFunc);
    for (ClassA aObj : a) {
        LocalDate dateA = aObj.getDate();
        T tToUse = null;
        for (T tObj : t){
            LocalDate dateT = dateGetter.apply(tObj);
            if (dateT.isAfter(dateA)){
                break;
            }
            tToUse = tObj; 
        }
        setter.accept(aObj, tObjToUse);
    }
}
```

Call as follows:

```java
mapClassToClassA(b, a, ClassB::getDate, ClassA::setClassB);
mapClassToClassA(c, a, ClassC::getDate, ClassA::setClassC);
```

Comment: Greet's base "Dated" interface solution is nice, but yours is more elegant imo. Extracting the 2 functions to be parameters makes it really flexible.

Comment: Thank you!!!! This is great!
I cant add a common interface.

Answer (score 1):

That's what interfaces are for, no?

```
public interface Dated {
  LocalDate getDate();
} 

public class ClassB implements Dated {
  ...
}

public class ClassC implements Dated {
  ...
}
```

And for the setter, you can use `instanceOf`.

```
public void mapClassBToClassA(List<? extends Dated> b, List<ClassA> a){
   Comparator<Dated> sortFunc = Comparator.comparing(Dated::getDate);
   Collections.sort(b, sortFunc);
   for (ClassA aObj : a){
      LocalDate dateA = aObj.getDate();
      Dated datedToUse = null;
      for (Dated bObj : b){
         LocalDate dateB = bObj.getDate();
         if (dateB.isAfter(dateA)){
            break;
         }
         else {
            datedToUse = bObj; 
         } 
      }
      if (datedToUse instanceOf ClassB bObjToUse) {
         aObj.setClassB(bObjToUse);
      }
      else if (datedToUse instanceOf ClassC cObjToUse) {
         aObj.setClassC(cObjToUse);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for input, buy I cant change ClassB, ClassC

Answer (score -1):

If you are interested in performance, first of all you should also sort the A (the second) list.

When you find the closest younger (dateToUse) in the B list (the first list) then for the next item from A list you can start the B list looping from that point.

Sorting both lists you will get N (linear) complexity instead of N^2 that you have now.

Comment: You'll get N log(N) complexity because that's the complexity of sorting.

Comment: Storing the Bs and Cs in a `TreeMap` and then calling `floorEntry` will give N log(N) as well. First N log(N) to create the `TreeMap`, then N (loop over A) times log(N) (getting the floor entry) for finding the matching B or C instance. `floorEntry` will be useful here because it returns the entry with the largest key that's not larger than the input - just what the current loop is finding.

Comment: @RobSpoor
I think your calculation of the (time) complexity for the presented algorithm (+ sorting && delooping on list B) is wrong. 

The error is in the "Delta" - input increase.  
You calculated the complexity only for A list, but that is not the total increment of the input as the input for the algorithm is A and B. 
If you calculate the complexity for "Deltas" A and B you will see that sorting A and delooping B is always better than TreeMap's floorEntry.

Comment: @RobSpoor If you are not convinced with "Delta"-based complexity proof let me present such a reasoning:  For sorting (me) and creating TreeMap (you) we both need  "n log n" complexity. So far we are set. But later - my algorithm is linear, I need 2 pointers to iterate the 2 tables only once. I have no best, no average, no worst cases. And what you have? In the best case you have what I have i.e. your floorEntry gets at the first fetch in the tree, but in the avg and worst cases deeper tree levels must be visited: n log n.   So your algorithm meets mine only in the best case.

Comment: Notabene the best case is absolutely trivial - the median date of the B list must be the closest date "after" for all A dates.

Comment: Sorting a list or using a `TreeMap` both have the same time complexity but this demonstrates that time complexity is not the complete answer. Sorting an `ArrayList` with the reference implementation has a best case of *n* while populating a `TreeMap` is always *n log n*. Then, `TreeMap` creates a node object for each element behind the scenes, which has to be initialized and traversed unlike the flat array of an `ArrayList`. But note that you can simply replace the inner loop with `Collections.binarySearch` to get rid of the quadratic time complexity, without sorting the other list.

Comment: @Holger 
Collections.binarySearch makes no sense, because to use it you must have the B list sorted.
But if you have the B list sorted you can just keep track of the pointers of both sorted lists: A nad B going forward, no binary search is needed.  BTW binarySearch is n log n, the same complexity like creating balanced binary tree.

Comment: @Talavera316 the B list *is* already sorted in the original code, unlike list A. So you can replace the inner loop with binary search without the need to touch anything else, most notably without adding a sort operation for list A. I didn’t dismiss your idea, but it’s a significant change while it’s not predictable whether it will pay off—too little information about the real case has been given. Both alternatives get rid of the quadratic time complexity that’s all that can be said.